# Flyway can't access resources during testing after adding `module-info.java`

Tags: java, flyway, java-10, java-module

After upgrading to Java 10 (from 8), I managed to get everything working, but after adding `module-info.java`, one of the problems I'm having is that Flyway can't access the SQL files when running the tests from the command line.

Starting the app or running the tests from IntelliJ work (but I found that many module related problems do not become apparent when running things on IntelliJ). When starting the application with `mvn spring-boot:run` it works fine, but building the application with `mvn package` fails at the testing task with this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain input
stream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) [spring-boot-test-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain inputstream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathResource.loadAsString(ClassPathResource.java:91) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.AbstractLoadableResource.checksum(AbstractLoadableResource.java:37) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.scanForMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:148) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:108) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:44) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:131) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:113) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:99) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:44) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:121) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$1.call(DbValidate.java:158) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$1.call(DbValidate.java:151) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:151) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1031) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:78) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:918) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:910) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1238) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:910) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 44 common frames omitted

2018-06-29 14:03:38.432 ERROR 18664 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5a1de7fb] to prepare test instance [tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver.DashmanserverApplicationTests@30c19bff]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to o
btain inputstream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.context@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.boot@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain inputstream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathResource.loadAsString(ClassPathResource.java:91) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.AbstractLoadableResource.checksum(AbstractLoadableResource.java:37) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.scanForMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:148) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:108) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:44) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:131) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:113) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:99) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:44) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:121) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$1.call(DbValidate.java:158) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$1.call(DbValidate.java:151) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:151) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1031) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:78) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:918) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:910) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1238) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:910) ~[flyway-core-5.1.3.jar:na]
        at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at spring.beans@5.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 44 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.484 s <<< FAILURE! - in tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver.DashmanserverApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver.DashmanserverApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to o
btain inputstream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain inputstream for resource: db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   DashmanserverApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Appli...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-29T14:03:39+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project dashmanserver: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashmanserver\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I'm guessing the module system is preventing access to those files, but because I can't replicated it while running it from IntelliJ, I can't debug it to get more details. Any ideas about how the module system may be impacting the loading of resource files?

I tried adding:

```
opens tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver to spring.core;
```

to my module in case that would help, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You opened the `tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver` package, but that package is not where `db/migration/V0002__enable_uuid.sql` resides.  Opening the `db.migration` package should do the trick.

Modules are encapsulated, which means other code (like Flyway) isn’t allowed to look at their inner workings.  Effectively, all .jar entries are private, except for classes, and files in opened packages.

The documentation for both Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream state:

> Resources in named modules are subject to the rules for encapsulation specified in the Module `getResourceAsStream` method and so this method returns `null` when the resource is a non-"`.class`" resource in a package that is not open to the caller's module.

[The documentation for Module.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) explains the encapsulation rules:

> A resource in a named module may be encapsulated so that it cannot be located by code in other modules. Whether a resource can be located or not is determined as follows:
>
> - If the resource name ends with "`.class`" then it is not encapsulated.
> - A *package name* is derived from the resource name. If the package name is a package in the module then the resource can only be located by the caller of this method when the package is open to at least the caller's module. If the resource is not in a package in the module then the resource is not encapsulated.

Comment: Thank you. Does this imply that the module for migrations should be `tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver.db.migrations` or something like that, for consistency?

Comment: That would be nice, but I’m not sure if Flyway can be directed to look in that location.